# How do I get access to filehandle and format respectively by typeglob?

Tags: perl, typeglob

[image]

It seems `filehandle` and `format` doesn't have any prefix,so I can't get reference to them by tricks like `%{*spud}`.

Is there anything I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

How do I access the `format`? Why do `$fd=*STDOUT` and `$fd=\*STDOUT` both work?

**UPDATE2**

Code:

```
package Foo;
our $spud = 'a scalar';
our @spud = 'an array';
our %spud = (a => 'hash');
sub spud {}
format spud =
.
open 'spud', $0; 

my $stash = \%Foo::;
my $name  = 'spud';
my $glob  = $$stash{$name};

for my $type (qw(SCALAR ARRAY HASH CODE IO FORMAT)) {
    #this works
    #print *$glob{$type}, $/; 
    #this doesn't work,only output one row of scalar                                  
    print *{$FOO::{spud}}{$type}, $/; 
}
```

Output:

```
[root@perl]# perl tb
SCALAR(0xa4dcf30)





[root@perl]#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{package Foo;
    our $spud = 'a scalar';
    our @spud = 'an array';
    our %spud = (a => 'hash');
    sub spud {}
    format spud =
.
    open 'spud', $0;
}

my $stash = \%Foo::;
my $name  = 'spud';
my $glob  = $$stash{$name};

for my $type (qw(SCALAR ARRAY HASH CODE IO FORMAT)) {
     print *$glob{$type}, $/;
}
```

prints:

```
SCALAR(0x810070)
ARRAY(0x81c750)
HASH(0x81bb00)
CODE(0x81bbd0)
IO::Handle=IO(0x81b670)
FORMAT(0x81bc40)
```

Comment: So FORMAT can only be accessed by hash key instead of some prefix?

Comment: I don't quite understand how `*$glob{$type}` work here...Can you elaborate about it?

Comment: @R__ => you can think of a glob as a restricted hash that only has keys corresponding to Perl's core datatypes. so if `$type` is `ARRAY` then `*$glob{$type}` will return a reference to the `ARRAY` stored in the glob (in this case `@Foo::spud`).  You can of course do this without all of the variable indirection: `*{$Foo::{spud}}{ARRAY}`

Comment: @R__ => yes, the `FORMAT` and `IO` types do not have their own sigils, so to access them directly you need to access their slot in the glob.

Comment: you mentioned that perl will automatically dereference a typeglob used as file handle,if that's the case,why `\\*STDOUT` doesn't work? I assume it should work by dereference **twice**.

Comment: I just tried `*{$Foo::{spud}}{$type}`,it can only dump `SCALAR(0x810070)`

Comment: @R__ => perl will not dereference the value twice, once is all you get for free.  You are probably only finding the scalar because the rest of the values are not defined in your script.  Accessing the scalar slot of a glob will cause the scalar to autovivify.  None of the other types will autovivify in this way, so that is why you are not seeing them.  Define them like I did in the example above and the syntax should work.

Comment: I defined them as you did,but `print *{$FOO::{spud}}{$type}, $/; ` only prints the scalar(first one),but `print *$glob{$type}, $/;` works as expected...

Comment: @R__, A glob is a structure with multiple fields. You can use a syntax similar to hashes to access to fields.`*$glob{$type}` gets  you the "`$type`" field of the glob.

Comment: @ikegami ,all I've learned is to use `$` for scalar,`@` for array and `%` for hash,never seen `*` as a prefix...should `*$glob{$type}` be interpreted as `*$glob` and then `{type}` or `*` and `$glob{$type}`?

Comment: @R__ => sigils always bind tightly, so `*$glob{$type}` is `*{$glob}{$type}`

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right package?  `Foo::` and `FOO::` are different.

Answer (score 0):

*spud will give you the filehandle from the type glob.  See here: [Typeglobs and Filehandles](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/prog3/ch02_10.htm)

Comment: Also,I don't understand why `$fh = *STDOUT;` is the same as `$fh = \*STDOUT;`...something & reference to something should be different,right?

Comment: @R__ => when working with file handles, Perl does not usually care if you give it a glob or a ref to a glob, it will automatically do the right thing.  This is one of the only times where Perl will automatically dereference something.

Comment: @R__, `*STDOUT` (a glob) is NOT the same as `\*STDOUT` (a ref to a glob). Lots of builtins simply accept both.